# Update graphs automatically in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, dashboard

Based on this [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6bd13f974d6516f3e491) I created two graphs with two metrics each. Every 5 seconds reads from a csv file showing cpu %user and cpu %system in the first graph and memory free - memory used in the second one.

The problem is that updates only the first line of the first graph.
When I remove cpu %user it updates only the cpu %system. I cannot update all the metrics in both graphs with their axes as well.

Is there any obvious mistake here?
Is there any other tutorial similar to what I'm trying to do in d3.js?

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}


</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var user = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.user); });

var system = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.system); });

var memFree = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.memFree); });

var memUsed = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.memUsed); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var chart1 = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var chart2 = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.timestamp = parseTime(d.timestamp);
          d.user = +d.user;
          d.system = +d.system;
          d.memFree = +d.memFree;
          d.memUsed = +d.memUsed;
    });

    var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.user, d.system); });
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
    y.domain([min, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.user, d.system); })]);

      chart1.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "userLine")
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .attr("d", user(data));

  chart1.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "systemLine")
      .style("stroke", "blue")
      .attr("d", system(data));

  // Add the X Axis
  chart1.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  chart1.append("g")
      .call(yAxis);

  chart1.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/4) + "," + y(data[0].user) + ")")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "green")
    .text("%user");

  chart1.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/5) + "," + y(data[0].system) + ")")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .text("%system");

});

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.timestamp = parseTime(d.timestamp);
          d.user = +d.user;
          d.system = +d.system;
          d.memFree = +d.memFree;
          d.memUsed = +d.memUsed;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
  var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.memFree, d.memUsed); });
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
  y.domain([min, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.memFree, d.memUsed); })]);

  chart2.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "memFreeLine")
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .attr("d", memFree(data));

  chart2.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "memUsedLine")
      .style("stroke", "blue")
      .attr("d", memUsed(data));

  // Add the X Axis
  chart2.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  chart2.append("g")
      .call(yAxis);

  chart2.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/4) + "," + y(data[0].memFree) + ")")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "green")
    .text("memFree");

  chart2.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + y(data[0].memUsed) + ")")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .text("memUsed");

});

setInterval(function() {
    updateChart1();
    updateChart2();
}, 5000); 

// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateChart1() {
    // Get the data again
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.timestamp = parseTime(d.timestamp);
          d.user = +d.user;
          d.system = +d.system;
          d.memFree = +d.memFree;
          d.memUsed = +d.memUsed;
        });

    var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.user, d.system); });
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
    y.domain([min, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.user, d.system); })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var chart1 = d3.select("svg").transition();

    // Make the changes
        chart1.select(".userLine")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", user(data));
        chart1.select(".systemLine")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", system(data));

        chart1.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        chart1.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}

function updateChart2() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.timestamp = parseTime(d.timestamp);
          d.user = +d.user;
          d.system = +d.system;
          d.memFree = +d.memFree;
          d.memUsed = +d.memUsed;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
    var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d.memFree, d.memUsed); });
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
    y.domain([min, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.memFree, d.memUsed); })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var chart2 = d3.select("svg").transition();

    // Make the changes
        chart2.select(".memFreeLine")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", memFree(data));
        chart2.select(".memUsedLine")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", memUsed(data));
        chart2.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        chart2.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm almost sure about what's the problem, but before I write an answer, can you paste **your** code?

Comment: Updated my question @GerardoFurtado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem: you're selecting the same element inside both your `updateChart` functions:

```
chart1.select(".line")//class here is "line"
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", user(data));
chart1.select(".line")//class here is "line" again!
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", system(data));
```

See? You're selecting the same class (`.line`) for both the user and the system data.

**Solution:**

In the initial painting, set different classes:

```
chart1.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "userLine")//specific class
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr("d", user(data));

chart1.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "systemLine")//specific class
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("d", system(data));
```

And then, update each one individually:

```
chart1.select(".userLine")//selecting different classes...  
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", user(data));
chart1.select(".systemLine")//selecting different classes...  
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", system(data));
```

Comment: I've changed the line to userLine, systemLine, memFreeLine and memUsedLine and now it doesn't update anything. Not even the first line of the first graph.

Comment: The other mistake I can see is this line, that you should remove: `var chart1 = d3.select("svg").transition();` The problem you had was clear. At this point, I can't help anymore unless you create a working plunker or fiddle with the data.

Comment: I updated my code with the new classes. When I removed the line var chart1 = d3.select("svg").transition(); I got an error Uncaught TypeError: chart1.select(...).duration is not a function. Thank you for your help Gerardo

Comment: As I told you: I cannot test it without a working code, with the data. Please create any working example, it will be easier to me or someone else helping you.

Comment: Thank you @Gerardo. My last mistake was var chart1 = d3.select("svg").transition(); The correct one is to select the body element, not the svg. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Of course, I had also to change the classes of the x and y axis accordingly.